# How to join multiple DataTable for Google chart

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I want to draw multiple line charts those x-axis are `Date`.

```
function drawChart() {
    var chartData = [
        [["date", "chart1"],
            [new Date('2017-02-06'), 0.73], [new Date('2017-02-02'), 0.84], [new Date('2017-02-01'), 1.0], [new Date('2017-01-31'), 0.97],
            [new Date('2017-01-30'), 0.86], [new Date('2017-01-25'), 0.88]],
        [["date", "chart2"],
            [new Date('2017-02-16'), 0.52], [new Date('2017-02-22'), 0.43]],
        [["date", "chart3"],
            [new Date('2017-02-21'), 0.6], [new Date('2017-02-22'), 0.42], [new Date('2017-02-15'), 0.61], [new Date('2017-02-20'), 0.56]]
    ]
    var options = {
        title: 'joined chart'
    };
    var dt1 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chartData[0]);
    var dt2 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chartData[1]);
    var dt3 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chartData[1]);
    var data = google.visualization.data.join(dt1, dt2, 'full', [[0, 0]], [1], [1]);
    new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart-div')).draw(data, options);
}
```

When there are only two `DataTable` data it works as I expected.

[image]

To draw three lines I wrote like this:

```
var data3 = google.visualization.data.join(data, dt3, 'full', [[0, 0]], [1], [1]);
```

But then the result chart was not well drawn.

How can I join google chart `DataTable` more than two?

This is the code in jsfiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/fe26/gtf960nm/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way to combine two separate charts is using the `join` method:

```
var joinedData = google.visualization.data.join(dt1, data2, 'full', [[0, 0]], [1], [1]);
var joinedData2 = google.visualization.data.join(joinedData, dt3, 'full', [[0, 0]], [1,2], [1]);
```

Here the first two data sets are combined uding the `google.visualization.data.join` method. Then another third data set is combined to that one using the join method.

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/q5ft1dex/

Comment: What you wrote was a simple line charts. I want to know how to join two or more lines charts that have different x-axis values.

Comment: I see, I updated my answer, please take a look. I think this is what you want.